# Javascript React Component State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What does **[...Array(totalStars)]** return below React Component?

Does it return an array with length of 5 and what are the exact elements in the array?

Thank you for answering.

```
class StarRating extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        totalStars: PropTypes.number
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        totalStars: 5
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            starsSelected: 0
        }
        this.change = this.change.bind(this)
    }

    change(starsSelected) {
        this.setState({starsSelected})
    }

    render() {
        const {totalStars} = this.props
        const {starsSelected} = this.state
        return (
            <div className="star-rating">
                {[...Array(totalStars)].map((n, i) =>
                    <Star key={i}
                          selected={i<starsSelected}
                          onClick={() => this.change(i+1)}
                    />
                )}
                <p>{starsSelected} of {totalStars} stars</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does [...Array(totalStars)] return below React Component?

> It creates an array with the length of 5 and Array has 5 undefined values, like [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined].

Does it return an array with length of 5 and what are the exact elements in the array?

> Yes, it returns an array length of 5. In your map function return 5 star elements.

Answer (score 1):

Hey it's not relate to React. It's pure ES6 scope.

To understand your code
`[...Array(totalStars)].map(` , it would be nice if you take a look at:

- Array(n): Create an arr with n empty elem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
- Destructuring assignment ES6

So you will never be confused again.
BTW, you can run the example code in the browser console (and can set breakpoint to debug it) to see the reality:

```
[...Array(5)].map((n,i) => console.log(n,i));
```

Answer (score 0):

`...` is a spread operator (new operator released in ES6).

What spread operator doing here is creating an array containing 5 places according to the value given to it `Array(totalStars)`.